# geeglm not recognizing clusters

Tags: r, model, fitting, generalized-estimating-equations, cluster-sample

I am fitting a geeglm model and it is not recognizing the clustering.

my model is

```
geeglm(formula = Consumption~Price + Income + Embargod + Observation, 
   id=Id, 
   waves=Observation,
   corstr="ar1")
```

and the (partial) output is

```
Estimated Correlation Parameters:
  Estimate Std.err
  alpha        0       0
Number of clusters:   342   Maximum cluster size: 1
```

Why is it saying that I have 342 clusters and the max cluster size is 1?

Id is a factor variable with 18 levels and 19 observations in each, so there should be 18 clusters with a max size of 19.

Comment: The documentation says: "**waves**
Wariable[sic] specifying the ordering of repeated mesurements on the same unit. Also used in connection with missing values. See examples below." Of which there are no examples. Basically you have to tabulate `Observation` against `Id`. They are taken as crossnested effects.

Answer (score 1):

The geeglm function requires that your data be ordered by time (or observation) within each level. Once your data is ordered that way, you should get the proper output. See this document for an example dataset: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/vignettes/geepack-manual.pdf